# destructive method and bang method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

*David A. Black* said in his Book:

> Dangerous can mean whatever the person writing the method wants it to mean. In the case of the built-in classes, it usually means this method, unlike its non-bang equivalent,
>   permanently modifies its receiver. It doesn’t always, though: exit! is a dangerous alternative to exit, in the sense that it doesn’t run any finalizers on the way out of the program.
>
> The danger in sub! (a method that substitutes a replacement string for a matched pattern in a string) is partly that it changes its receiver and partly that it returns `nil` if no change has taken place—unlike sub, which always returns a copy of the original string with the replacement (or no replacement) made.

While all the above is understood,but couldn't understand what he tried to say in the below.

> ***Furthermore, don’t assume a direct correlation between bang methods and destructive methods. They often coincide, but they’re not the same thing.***

Based on what notion we can classify and put a method in the destructive or dangerous list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructive methods are those, that change the value of an attribute of the object they're called on. So what he says can be reiterated as:

> Don't assume that `method!` will change a value of an attribute. This is often the case, but  not a rule.

Comment: OK. As you said `Destructive methods are those, that change the value of an attribute of the object they're called on` is same as `bang` method right? Then why he said that they sometimes same- *which you answered*, but sometimes not same - what he means here?

Comment: It means you (or other programmer) can define a method called `destroy!`, but it will in fact do no destructive actions. The bang notation is just a convention, and it's up to the programmer to decide whether he will follow it or not. As a result, when you read other people's code, you also can't assume that they follow that convention.